# Spellchecker giving suggestions for correct words

Tags: solr, lucene, spell-checking, solrcloud, solr7

Querying an alias with 5 collections and getting suggestions for correct words as well.
Ex:- Collection1 has "tire policy" in it
Collection2 has a word "polite" in it.
When I query "tire policy" it checks and returns "polite" as a suggestion for "policy".
P.S. - During query time i am passing

```
spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest=0
```

As without it spellchecker does not correct the wrong spellings.

I am using DirectSolrSpellchecker
Adjusted the 
`<float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>` to

```
<float name="maxQueryFrequency">1</float>
```

but getting the same issue.

## Direct solr spellchecker code-

```
 <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">text</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
       <str name="distanceMeasure">org.apache.lucene.search.spell.LevenshteinDistance</str>
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
      <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
      <int name="minQueryLength">3</int>
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">1</float>
    </lst>
```

## spellchecker inside handler

```
<str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">file</str>
        <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>
```

There should not be any suggestions for policy as "maxqueryfreqency" is set to "1".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to adjust the **maxResultsForSuggest** parameter?
With your current value of 5, if your query

> returns 5 or fewer results, the spellchecker will report
>   "correctlySpelled=false" and also offer suggestions

[solr 8.1 documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/spell-checking.html)

Comment: Thanks for replying. To answer the question, yes i had it 5 at first but i was facing this problem where for phrases it was always saying correctlySpelled=true and was not giving suggestions if one word was misspelled. So, i changed it to 0.

Comment: I recently changed spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest to 50000.